# Create an radio button list from array of elements using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui

I wanted to create a radio button list from an array of elements using angular js
ng-repeat.

Any example will help, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="element in elements">
      <input type="radio" ng-value="element"/ >
      {{element}}
    </label>

  </body>
</html>

angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.elements = [1,2,3,4,5];
    }]);
```

Plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/hNI5kjMHW6G9kSUeJtOp?p=preview

Use the directives `ng-app` and `ng-controller` to connect your controller with the view. In your controller, include `$scope` as a dependency and then set a variable on it containing an array of elements.

Use `ng-repeat` on the label element, and insert the value of the element with Angular expressions.

Hope this helps.